# Redirecting someone

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to redirect someone to index.php, how do i do this? But not the "meta" method, because it needs to be in header, and i can not have it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use JavaScript for this. If the user has JavaScript disabled (or most likely is browsing with a browser without support for JavaScript), the redirection will not work.

From your PHP code, you can send an HTTP header to direct your user to the page of your choice. Use the [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function to do this.

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit; // Important, stops execution of PHP page
```

If PHP complains that it cannot send the header because data has already been sent to the browser, simply go to the top of your script and enable output buffering by using [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start):

```
ob_start();
```

With output buffering enabled, you can send headers anywhere in your code since data is only sent at the end of your script.

> [PHP Documentation: `header()`](http://php.net/header)
>   [PHP Documentation: `ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.href = 'http://your-new-url.com';
```

or

```
window.location.pathname = 'index.php';
```

if you need to use a relative pathname.

Comment: It looks like I'm the only one still using the `href` property!

Comment: Looks like you are the only one doing it properly.

Comment: @voyager: Thanks for the edit. I didn't notice the OP hinted at a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com/index.php"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree with you about link-only answers, but this one links to the Mozilla Javascript doc, which I doubt is susceptible to move. Furthermore, the important thing here is the answer, the link is only here to provide more informations.